# Filtering on text column: full-text or separate table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so, which has 1 million+ rows:

```
+----+----------+----------------+------------+
| ID |   SSID   |      MAC       |  LOCATION  |  
+----+----------+----------------+------------+
|  1 | home_net | aa:bb:cc:dd:ee | Town North |  
|  2 | fly-fi   | aa:bb:cc:dd:ff | Town South |  
+----+----------+----------------+------------+
```

I often need to search for all rows with a given location. I have three ideas to structure the data so that I can filter based on location without using the slow "LIKE":

1. Add a fulltext index to the location column.
2. Create a new table for location and have a foreign key in the above table. Then I could filter based on the foreign key.
3. Create the table from point 2, and create a join table, like so:

> ```
> +-------------+-----------+
> | LOCATION ID | PROBE_IDS |
> +-------------+-----------+
> |           1 |         1 |
> |           1 |         2 |
> |           1 |         3 |
> |           1 |         4 |
> |           2 |         5 |
> |           2 |         6 |
> |           2 |         7 |
> +-------------+-----------+
> ```

Which of these options, or another, is best to structure the data given that many queries will be carried out which filter by location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a many-to-1 relationship, I would use option #2, the foreign key. The join table is more appopriate for many-to-many relationships.

The full-text index seems too heavyweight for short phrases like this. It might not even work for many locations, because full-text indexing has a minimum word length that it will index.